# mouse over image with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, mouseover

I need to swap the image out when it's moused over. It should be using `innerHTML` as well I believe.

```
<body>

<a href="#">anime</a>
<a href="#">ponies</a>
<h1 class="panel">What fandom is better?</h1>
<div class="anime"> <img src="img/anime.png"> </div>
<div class="pony">  <img src="img/pony.png"> </div>
<p id="answer">Choose One</p>
</body>
/**
 This is for element changes upon mousesing over of the area
 */` 
document.getElementsByClassName("anime")[0].onmouseover=
    function(){
        orangeBorder1();
        mouseAnime();
    }

document.getElementsByClassName("pony")[0].onmouseover=
    function(){
        orangeBorder();
        mousePony();
    }
function mousePony(){
    document.getElementById("pony").src="pony1.png";
}
```

Comment: You don't have anything with the id "pony" so it isn't grabbing anything. You should add the id "pony" to the img tag and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if your code is copied wrong but you don't have anything with an id of pony

getElementById will look for a tag with an attribute of `id`, specify that and your code should work.

id should be unique within the page. You should also give the div a id too instead of querying on the classname

Comment: The snippet with the Id pony was a left over of a previous attempt at using the ID to change the image. It wasn't working and I had removed the ID but forgot to remove the reference to the ID in script. It wasn't working due to some CSS errors and incorrect linking of an image.